# How to setup Magento CronJob?

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.9, observers

The custom module contains import of the CSV file in magento. I have changed availability to import file from the file located internally. Now I need to setup a cronjob witch will be importing or running the the import function.

Please have a look at the code below and compare if it is correct against the config.xml file.

```
app/code/community/Vehence/Exporter/Model/Importorders.php

class Vehence_Exporter_Model_Importorders extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public $order_info = array();
    public $order_item_info = array();
    public $order_item_flag = 0;
    public $store_id = 0;
    public $import_limit = 0;


    public function readCSV($csvFile,$data)
    {
        $this->import_limit = $data['import_limit'];
        $this->store_id = $data['store_id'];
        $file_handle = fopen('number1.csv', 'r'); //fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        $i=0;
        $decline = array();
        $available = array();
        $success = 0;
        $parent_flag = 0;
        $invalid = 0;
        $line_number = 2;
        $total_order = 0;
        Mage::helper('exporter')->unlinkFile();
        Mage::helper('exporter')->header();
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
        {
            $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle);

            if($i!=0)
            {
                if($line_of_text[$i][0]!='' && $parent_flag==0)
                 { 
               $this->insertOrderData($line_of_text[$i]); 
               $parent_flag = 1;
               $total_order++;
                 }
                else if($line_of_text[$i][91]!='' && $parent_flag == 1 && $line_of_text[$i][0]=='')
                  {
                    $this->insertOrderItem($line_of_text[$i]);
                   }
             else if($parent_flag==1)
             {
               try
               {
                $message = Mage::getModel('exporter/createorder')->createOrder($this->order_info,$this->order_item_info,$this->store_id);
                Mage::getModel('exporter/createorder')->removeOrderStatusHistory();
               } catch (Exception $e) {
                  Mage::helper('exporter')->logException($e,$this->order_info['increment_id'],'order',$line_number);
                  Mage::helper('exporter')->footer();
                  $decline[] = $this->order_info['increment_id'];
                  $message = 0;
                }

                if($message== 1)
                $success++;

                if($message== 2){
                  Mage::helper('exporter')->logAvailable($this->order_info['increment_id'],'order',$line_number);
                  Mage::helper('exporter')->footer();
                  $decline[] = $this->order_info['increment_id'];
                } 

                $this->order_info = array();
                $this->order_item_info = array();
                $this->order_item_flag = 0;

                $this->insertOrderData($line_of_text[$i]); 
                $parent_flag = 1; 
                $line_number = $i+1;
                $total_order++;
             }

            }

            $i++;

            if($this->import_limit < $total_order)
            break;
        }
        $isPrintable = Mage::helper('exporter')->isPrintable();
        if($success)
        Mage::getModel('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('exporter')->__('Total '.$success.' order(s) imported successfully!'));

        if($decline || $isPrintable)
        Mage::getModel('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('exporter')->__('Click <a href="'.Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("exporter/adminhtml_exporter/exportLog").'">here</a> to view the error log'));

        fclose($file_handle);

        return array($success,$decline);
    }
```

This is the config.xml file:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <vehence_importorders>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>importorders::readCSV</model></run>
        </vehence_importorders>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Answer (score 0):

You config.xml file needs just a minor update:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <vehence_importorders>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>vehence_exporter/importorders::readCSV</model></run>
        </vehence_importorders>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

You may also find that you need to update your readCSV function, as you can't pass arguments to it from Magento's crontab XML.